# Can I set two Different paths for two different versions of JDKs 32-bit and 64-bit

Tags: java, environment-variables, 32bit-64bit

Hi I need to keep both the versions of JDKs - 32-bit and 64-bit. The reason being in my project I need few application to run on 32 bit and rest in 64 bit.
So How can I set paths for two different JDKs in Environment Variable (PATH)?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't. Because java process to be invoked will be found from first set path.

Comment: But you can create batch/script file, which will set path and then runs java. The path set from batch/script will stay till batch/script completes.

Comment: @brbtea I am using windows. what can be the possible solution?

Comment: use batch file. Create batch file, which will first set path to 64 bit or 32 bit JDK. Google how to set path using batch file. Then from batch file execute java/javac. The executed java/javac will be from path you set before in batch file.

Comment: People here in BufferOverflow are to help one who need ;)